# Mapping code to display in API information in one table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

how can i map my code to display the information on table style fetched from this two ONLINE api's? right now my code displays the information but in two separate tables because its being mapped twice. i want it to display it in one table. ***How can i map the code for it to display all the API information in one table***

[1] How is displaying right now -- > https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D14i.jpg , [2] How it should display -- > https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoauM.jpg , [3] API information -- > https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVvgG.jpg , https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETb99.jpg , [ERROR]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTOxm.jpg , [LOOPHOLE]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Adl.jpg

***MY CODE THAT FETCHES THE APIS AND SHOW TABLES***

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Ranking = () => {
  const [playerName, setPlayerName] = useState([]);
  const [playerRank, setPlayerRank] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = () => {
    const playerAPI = 'http://localhost:3008/api/players';
    const playerRank = 'http://localhost:3008/api/highscore/players';

    const getINFOPlayer = axios.get(playerAPI)
    const getPlayerRank = axios.get(playerRank)
    axios.all([getINFOPlayer, getPlayerRank]).then(
      axios.spread((...allData) => {
        const allDataPlayer = allData[0].data.players
        const getINFOPlayerRank = allData[1].data.players

        setPlayerName(allDataPlayer)
        setPlayerRank(getINFOPlayerRank)
      })
    )
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
      </tr>
        <tbody>
          {playerName?.map((name) => {
            return (
              <tr key={name}>
                <td>{name.name}</td>
                <td>{name.id}</td>
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          {playerRank?.map((name) => {
            return (
              <tr key={name}>
                <td>{name.id}</td>
                <td>{name.score}</td>
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>


    </table>
  )
}

export default Ranking
```

***CODE WITH IMPLEMENTATIONS FROM SMACKSS ANSWER***

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Ranking = () => {
  const [playerName, setPlayerName] = useState([]);
  const [playerRank, setPlayerRank] = useState([]);
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = () => {
    const playerAPI = 'http://localhost:3008/api/players';
    const playerRank = 'http://localhost:3008/api/highscore/players';

    const getINFOPlayer = axios.get(playerAPI)
    const getPlayerRank = axios.get(playerRank)
    axios.all([getINFOPlayer, getPlayerRank]).then(
      axios.spread((...allData) => {
        const allDataPlayer = allData[0].data.players
        const getINFOPlayerRank = allData[1].data.players
        const newPlayer = allDataPlayer.map(name => {
          const pr = getINFOPlayerRank.find(rank => name.id === rank.id)

        
          return {
            id: name.id,
            name: name.name,
            status: name.status,
            position: pr.position,
            score: pr.score
          }
        
          // or simply do the following if the keys doesn't matter: return {...name, ...pr}
        })

        setPlayerName(allDataPlayer)
        setPlayerRank(getINFOPlayerRank)
        
        console.log(newPlayer)
        setPlayer(newPlayer)
      })
    )
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
      </tr>
        <tbody>
        {player?.map((name) => {
  return (
      <tr key={name}>
         <td>{name.name}</td>
         <td>{name.id}</td>
         <td>{name.status}</td>
         <td>{name.position}</td>
         <td>{name.score}</td>
      </tr>
    )
})}
        </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

export default Ranking
```

Comment: What is the relation between `id`s in each API?

Comment: the ID from the first api is the same id as the second api, and each ID matches the name of the first api. so eventually after i fetch both information on one table, what i will want to do is ID = ID = NAME fetch NAME instead of ID.

Comment: thank you that fixed the error i was getting, now it goes okay and i get no error but i do get this on console : Array [] , length: 0, <prototype>: Array [] and the page does not displays the outcome of the apis, only the table names

Comment: yes, just updated it i was doing it right when you asked.

Comment: also i get : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: playerRank.find is not a function (N

Comment: i just fixed that error moving the const up i will update code.

Comment: and yes, data is being returned correctly because the first code works

Comment: updated code now i get no error but data not showing

Comment: There is no problem with the position of variables, but you should change `playerName` to `allDataPlayer` and `playerRank` to `getINFOPlayerRank` in my pieces of code, I was dumb and sorry for did not point it out. You should've used the actual variable names that you get to store your values. My variable names were only for demonstration. Because the actual states would not be updated right away and you can access the next value of them only in `useEffect` hooks.

Comment: if i do that i get : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: pr is undefined