# display async api request on react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

i have this code that shows the data on console but how can i display the data of all 3 apis at the same time on the page using react app .JSX using .map ?

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const urls = [
      "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
      "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
      "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
      "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
    ];

    const requests = urls.map((url) => fetch(url));
    const responses = await Promise.all(requests);
    const errors = responses.filter((response) => !response.ok);

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      throw errors.map((response) => Error(response.statusText));
    }

    const json = responses.map((response) => response.json());
    const data = await Promise.all(json);

    data.forEach((datum) => console.log(datum));
  }
  catch (errors) {
    errors.forEach((error) => console.error(error));
  }
})();
```

Comment: set the data resolved from `promise.all` to a state variable and map over it ..

Comment: can you give me an example as in code ? please, im pretty new to this fetching stuff

Comment: sure .... will add in few mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Promise.All method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and save the resolved data to a state and map accordingly to render data ...

A sample e.g. below

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const urls = [
  "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
  "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
  "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
  "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
];

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const promises = urls.map((url) =>
      fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => data)
    );
    Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
      setData(values);
    });
  }, []);

  if (!data) return "Loading ..."; // this is not exact way to do a loading state just for illustration ...

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <p key={item.id}>{item.value}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: you are wc  ...

Comment: hey would you mind checking this question out? i have a website that im doing and im having this issue with api, maybe you could help me there too if you don't mind i explain everything here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74249292/mapping-code-to-display-in-api-information-in-one-table

Comment: @yandrysantana tbh I didn't understand what you are trying there ...

Comment: I'm sorry, basically if you see the code the part where const pr = getINFOPlayerRank.find(rank => name.id === rank.id) if i leave it like that i get an error of PR UNDEFINED, but if i change it to const pr = getINFOPlayerRank.find(name => name.id === name.id) i get the table with the first api showing all information but the second api repeats the one data over and over, is there any way i can send you pictures so you have a better idea? this is my discord if you dont mind adding me so i can explain with pictures: yandr1#1755

Comment: @yandrysantana It would be easy to understand the issue if you can create a runnable sample and share the link, you can use codesandbox / stackblitz / w/e works for you  (add code, save and share the link) .... in the Q itself

Comment: working on codesandbox right now thank you! will send it when ready, also i just asked a clearer question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74272709/react-js-undefined-error-on-code-when-fetching-api