# react js undefined error on code when fetching api

Tags: javascript

i have this code that is giving me Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: pr is undefined

[image]

when i change

`const pr = getINFOPlayerRank.find(rank => name.id === rank.id)`

to

`const pr = getINFOPlayerRank.find(name => name.id === name.id)`

i get a response and table shows but the second api only displays the first line of data over and over:

[image]

***MY CODE***

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const News = () => {
  const [playerName, setPlayerName] = useState([]);
  const [playerRank, setPlayerRank] = useState([]);
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = () => {
    const playerAPI = 'http://localhost:3008/api/players';
    const playerRank = 'http://localhost:3008/api/highscore/players';

    const getINFOPlayer = axios.get(playerAPI)
    const getPlayerRank = axios.get(playerRank)
    axios.all([getINFOPlayer, getPlayerRank]).then(
      axios.spread((...allData) => {
        const allDataPlayer = allData[0].data.players
        const getINFOPlayerRank = allData[1].data.players
        const newPlayer = allDataPlayer.map(name => {
          const pr = getINFOPlayerRank.find(rank => name.id === rank.id)

        
          return {
            id: name.id,
            name: name.name,
            status: name.status,
            position: pr.position,
            score: pr.score
          }
        
          // or simply do the following if the keys doesn't matter: return {...name, ...pr}
        })

        setPlayerName(allDataPlayer)
        setPlayerRank(getINFOPlayerRank)
        
        console.log(newPlayer)
        setPlayer(newPlayer)
      })
    )
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
      </tr>
        <tbody>
        {player?.map((name) => {
  return (
      <tr key={name}>
         <td>{name.name}</td>
         <td>{name.id}</td>
         <td>{name.status}</td>
         <td>{name.position}</td>
         <td>{name.score}</td>
      </tr>
    )
})}
        </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}


export default News
```

Comment: It means that `getINFOPlayerRank.find(rank => name.id === rank.id)` doesn't find anything. There is at least one rank where the ID doesn't match any of the items in `getINFOPlayerRank`. Examine your data and adjust your code. If not all data is covered then you can simply skip items that do not exist in both arrays. If all are *supposed* to exist in both arrays, then there is a problem with how `getINFOPlayerRank` and/or `allDataPlayer` is created. Or they are simply the wrong data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using optional chanining:

```
return {
   id: name.id,
   name: name.name,
   status: name.status,
   position: pr?.position,
   score: pr?.score
}
```

Comment: this just fixed the issue, now all the Rank Matches the ID's Thank you so much!

Comment: It was a pleasure to help.